# Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be integrable. If $\int_K g \, d m = 0$ for every compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $g = 0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need to prove the statement:

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be Lebesgue integrable. If $\int_K g \, d m = 0$ for every compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $g = 0$ a.e.

Note that $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Here's what I have so far:

**Proof**

Suppose to the contrary that $m([g>t]) > 0$ for some $t > 0$. Recall that $m([g>t]) = \sup\{m(K) : K \ \text{is compact and} \ K \subset [g>t]\}$.

Choose $K \subseteq [g>t]$ such that $m([gg>t]) > m(K) \geq  m([g>t])/2$. Then notice

$$
0 = \int_K g \, dm = \int g\chi_{_K}\, dm \geq \int t\chi_{_K} \, dm \geq tm(K) > 0.
$$

This is a contradiction to the fact that $tm(K)$ is a positive number, and so we must conclude that $m([g>0]) =0 $. A similar argument shows that $m([g<0]) = 0$. This proves that $m([g\neq0]) = 0$.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't gotten anywhere, I am stuck. Not looking for an answer, just some guidance.

Comment: You can conclude $m(f > 0) = 0.$ But is obvious then that $m(f < 0) = 0$ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, on the contrary, $\mathrm{X} = \{g > t\}$ for some $t > 0$ had positive measure, then, by intersecting with a large compact set, we can assume $\mathrm{X}$ has compact closure and, in particular, finite measure. The regularity of the measure allows deducing that there exists a compact $\mathrm{K}$ contained in $\mathrm{X}$ whose measure is at least half that of $\mathrm{X}$ and therefore a contradiction. Q.E.D.

Comment: How did you use the fact that $\int_K g \, dm = 0$?

Comment: $\int_K g \geq t m(K) > 0.$

Comment: Actually, you don't need $X$ to have finite measure, regularity holds even for infinite measure sets.

Comment: So, you are choosing a compact set $K$ by using the fact that $m(X) = \sup\{m(K) : K \ \text{is compact and} \ K \subset X\}$?

Comment: Yes. Do you want me to write a full solution?

Comment: I just realised that you wrote a solution, which is fundamentally correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out!